# get_terms 'number' parameter does not appear to work

Tags: terms

Why doesn't the [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) call return 10 max results as requested? I'm baffled.

```
    $args = array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'video_tag',
            'parent'        => 0,
            'number'        => 10   
    );      
    error_log("JPH get_terms args: " . print_r($args,true));
    $children = get_terms( $args );
    error_log("JPH taxonomy: " . count( $children) . " total");
```

Resulting output in log is

> JPH get_terms args: Array\n(\n    [parent] => 0\n    [number] => 10\n 
>   [taxonomy] => video_tag\n)\n JPH taxonomy: 24806 total

I'm using PHP 7.1 and WordPress 4.8.2

Comment: Have you made sure there are no hooks involved (`pre_get_terms`, `get_terms_args` come to mind)?

Comment: Hmm there are none in the code and I've disabled all other plugins. I hooked in to `get_terms_args` with priority 999 and I can see the parameter 'number' is set to 10.

Comment: What does `print_r($children)` prints?

Answer (score 1):

So here's some info for any other people with this issue.

`get_terms` will not use the `number` parameter under certain conditions, such as if you pass in a `parent` parameter or if the `hierarchical` parameter is `true`. In these cases I have tried two workarounds, neither very good.

1. You can call `get_terms` then do an `array_slice` on the results afterwards. However if you have a ton of taxonomies then WordPress can run out of memory during the `get_terms` call, which was my original issue.
2. You can hook into the filter `terms_clauses` and force the `get_terms` call to use a LIMIT in its sql call. However this applies to all calls of `get_terms` across WordPress and not just the one in my custom code, and I don't want to cause unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Note this condition on the limit part of the `WP_Term_Query` [[src]](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php#L554):

```
// Don't limit the query results when we have to descend the family tree.
if ( $number && ! $hierarchical && ! $child_of && '' === $parent ) {
    if ( $offset ) {
        $limits = 'LIMIT ' . $offset . ',' . $number;
    } else {
        $limits = 'LIMIT ' . $number;
    }
} else {
    $limits = '';
}
```

where by default *child_of* is 0, *parent* is an empty string and *hierarchical*  is `true`.

Let's check two cases:

**A)** To limit the term results to top-level terms of a **hierarchical** taxonomy, we can use:

```
$args = [
    'taxonomy'     => 'category',
    'parent'        => 0,
    'number'        => 10,
];
```

In this case the `WP_Term_Query` fetches all top-level terms and then uses an array slice [[src](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php#L802)] to limit the results, according to the *number* input. For pagination, we can also add the *offset*.

**B)** In the case of a **non-hierarchical** taxonomy, we can use:

```
$args = [
    'taxonomy'     => 'post_tag',
    'number'        => 10,
];
```

where we shouldn't need to explicitly set the *parent* as 0. Every term is top-level. Here the term results are limited by the `LIMIT` in the SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the code block. I'm already using case A but it doesn't limit the results to 10. I can confirm for 'number' to work I would need to set 'hierarchical' to false and 'parent' to an empty string. :(

Comment: In that case the array_slice should kick in. You should debug that part. Does it work for the default category taxonomy?